# How to return an NSString * in Objective C (keep getting invalid summary)

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nsstring

So I presume this is a memory issue, here's the code:

```
- (NSString *)giveMeAStringGoddammit
{  
  NSString *s;
  // switch statement to choose which string to assign to s, so essentially:
  s = @"a string";      
  return s;  
}
```

And the calling code:

```
NSString *aString;
aString = [self giveMeAStringGoddammit];
```

However after this call, aString has an invalid summary when debugged and crashes when run.
I suspect I'm missing a retain or something, can someone help? Thanks.

Comment: When you have a static string, you don't need to retain it, so there is something that you're not showing which is causing the problem.

Comment: You need to show more code. Either you're returning a released object, or your switch isn't comprehensive and you're actually getting past it without ever assigning to `s` (which means it's a garbage value)

Comment: aString is actually a member variable for the class all this is in, if that makes a difference. This call is the first time it's assigned a value. Am trying the other suggestions now.

Comment: When is giveMeAStringGoddammit called? Is it in the constructor for the class? What is the value of self when it is called?

Comment: Thanks guys. It turns out the string was fine. The shitty debugger was saying "Invalid" in some places and the correct value in others. It prints out fine and all the operations using it are performed fine after that. My program still crashes for an unknown reason, but it's probably not due to this particular string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've got works just fine:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Test : NSObject
- (NSString *)giveMeAStringGoddammit;
@end

@implementation Test
- (NSString *)giveMeAStringGoddammit
{  
    NSString *s;
    // switch statement to choose which string to assign to s, so essentially:
    s = @"a string";      
    return s;  
}
@end

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        Test *t = [[Test alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"t says: %@", [t giveMeAStringGoddammit]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
t says: a string
```

To make this a little more realistic, let's change it to use a property:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Test : NSObject
@property(copy, nonatomic) NSString *string;
- (NSString *)giveMeAStringGoddammit;
@end

@implementation Test
@synthesize string;
- (NSString *)giveMeAStringGoddammit
{  
    NSString *s;
    // switch statement to choose which string to assign to s, so essentially:
    s = self.string;
    return s;  
}
@end

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        Test *t = [[Test alloc] init];
        t.string = @"Hello world!";
        NSLog(@"t says: %@", [t giveMeAStringGoddammit]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This does what you'd expect:

```
t says: Hello world!
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created a pointer object and it's expected to increment it's retain count whenever you referring them, for increasing retain count the string should be initiated and allocated with memory else you could use **[NSString stringwithString:[self giveMeAStringGoddammit]**. You can use this definition only when you exactly need it reference locally. because whenever you try to refer it out side the auto release pool will crash the app (hence it's not retained manually). So if you need to use it out side of the function, better use **[NSString alloc]init]**  and then load your string to the pointer object. 
**Well the way to make your code to work is add the lines
 `NSString *aString = [NSString  stringWithString:[self giveMeAStringGoddammit]];
    NSLog(@"My Str:%@",aString);` 
Hooray now the goddammit string was given......**